# Sidekiq worker writting in mysql performing better when single threaded

Tags: mysql, sidekiq, database-locking

I am using sidekiq to perform concurrently some kind of service, this service performs an INSERT on `table1` in mysql database. I noticed that on average my worker is performing way faster when I actually have one single thread running for the related queue (I am using sidekiq-limit-fetch whih enables to limit the number of threads per queue). 
I read that mysql is actually running LOCKS which actually locks the table or the row when an INSERT is performed. My guess is that, this is the reason why the worker is actually performing better when it is single threaded. 
How can I be sure this is the actual problem ? What can I do to fix this ? Is there a way not to lock the row or the table for these INSERT operations.

Comment: Too many ways to slow down MySQL.. what do your INSERTs look like? Do you also read from the rows/tables? Do you have indices? Maybe it helps drastically reducing the query cache.

Comment: @DanielW. My Insert is just writting to a dozen of different fields on one single table. I have a 3, 4 SELECTS before that because of association and validation. When I process those 1 after the other (only 1 database connection), the job takes approximately 20ms. However when I increase the number of threads and consequentely db connections this number goes up to 200ms

Comment: It makes sense that this number grows as we are increasing the load on the db and the number of connection...but 10 times, Id like to understand what's going on under the hood?